# Laravel LogServiceProvider won't let request go through

Tags: php, laravel, logging, fatal-error

Im trying to deploy a Laravel app which works fine in a local development environment.

However when I install it on the production server (no containers yet), I get the following error on each request:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider::configureErrorHandler() in
>   /var/www/some-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogServiceProvider.php:60

Anyone have experienced this? I'm running it along with nginx.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you included the correct module? It might be that you are calling wrong LogServiceProvider

Comment: How do I make sure?

Comment: If you are using Phpstorm IDE try to remove the include statement and check the suggestions they give you.

Comment: You can also try doing a fresh composer install by deleting your vendor folder. Try to replicate the issue on your dev machine and check if installing the project and updating it causes or solves the problem.

Comment: You can also try doing a fresh composer install by deleting your vendor folder. Try to replicate the issue on your dev machine and check if installing the project and updating it causes or solves the problem.

Comment: Try composer update -o   ( minus "o" letter)